# Uploading file to wordpress via xml-rpc and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, base64, xml-rpc

I am trying to write a chrome extension that can upload a picture to a wordpress blog. So far, so good, however the wordpress rpc api is expecting the picture in binary:

http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API/Media#wp.uploadFile

Unfortunately, the data I have is base64 encoded

http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab

When firing my code, the only feedback I get from Wordpress is: `faultCode -32700, parse error. not well formed`

This is it:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {"format": "png"}, function(img) {

    var data = new Object();
    data.name = 'Screenshot' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100); //pageTitle 
    data.overwrite = false;
    data.type = 'image/png'; //string:File MIME type.

    //transfrom screencapture into binary data for wordpress xmlrpc
    var regex = /^data:.+\/(.+);base64,(.*)$/;
    var matches = img.match(regex);
    data.bits = atob(matches[2]); //string: binary data. Shouldn't be base64-encoded.

    $.xmlrpc({
        url: wp.url,
        methodName: 'wp.uploadFile',
        params: [0, wp.user, wp.password, data],
        success: function(response, status, jqXHR) { 
            //this return the post id
            alert("worked :-)" + status + "/" + response + "/" +
                  jqXHR.responseXML + "/" + response.url); 
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error) { 
            alert("fail :-(" + status + " " + error + " " + jqXHR.responseXML); 
        }
    });
});
```

Do you have any idea how I could get this working? Thanks a million!

Comment: I swapped the data Object with a FormData object, like this, however t he xml-rpc plugin for jquery tells me, it is an unknown type. 

`var data = new FormData();
 data.append('bits', img);` 

Can you point me to a tutorial, example or be a bit more specific about the use of formData for xml-rpc? Thanks!

Comment: its a plain ajax option, http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/.  i havn't seen xmlrpc in years and i've never used the plugin. if you're sending xml, then i guess you might not me able to use it. you can always upload it apart from your other stuff; ajax can keep many balls in the air... still, even as you have it, you should be able to split the base64 file data on the server on ",", take segment 1, and then decode64(seg1) to get the binary data. you have to de-base64 the data to use FormData anyway, it's just a matter of where you want to do it: front or back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of hours, I finally figured it out. For anybody with the a similar problem.

1. There is a great Javascript library for Wordpress XML RPC on github that does all the magic  and comes with a lot of sample rpc's. It can be found at: http://github.com/developerworks/wordpress-xmlrpc-javascript-api
2. Uploading a picture with the help of the librabry was no big deal after all.

First you wanna decode the dataURL, you get from Chrome

```
var imageData = new Base64(atob(dataURL.split(',')[1]));
```

Afterwards, the upload...

```
var imageUpload = wp.uploadFile(1, {
    name: 'filename.png', 
    type: 'image/png', 
    bits: imageData,    
    overwrite: true
});
```

Comment: Hey i'm failed :( what is new Base64 ? please help me